# ReadFile + Eof Char

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm using serial com port communication **synchronously** with WinApi. And I want to split messages with **13** (CR). How can I use [ReadFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that it returns when it reads a 13 ?

---

The DCB struct has a field called `EofChar` but the function continues to read until it has filled the buffer. If I send only 3 bytes with a 13 it continues to wait for the 2 other bytes. Is it actually possible to make ReadFile read less bytes than the buffer provides and specified by `nNumberOfBytesToRead`?

- Incoming dec bytes: `12 12 13 15 18 19 ...`
- Wanted dec bytes: `12 12 13` (but unknown length)

---

**Code:**

```
// 2. reading:
DWORD bytesRead;
char* buffer = new char[5];
ReadFile(handle, buffer, 5, &bytesRead, NULL);
// bytesRead should be 3 in the example above

// 1. connecting:
HANDLE handle = CreateFile("COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
DCB dcb;
COMSTAT stat;
if (GetCommState(handle, &dcb))
{
    dcb.BaudRate          = 57600;      // baud rate
    dcb.ByteSize          = 7;          // number of bits/byte, 4-8 
    dcb.Parity            = EVENPARITY; // 0-4=no,odd,even,mark,space 
    dcb.StopBits          = ONESTOPBIT; // 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2  V2.12 0 -> ONESTOPBIT
    dcb.fBinary           = TRUE;       // binary mode, no EOF check 
    dcb.fParity           = TRUE;       // enable parity checking 
    dcb.fOutxCtsFlow      = FALSE;      // CTS output flow control 
    dcb.fOutxDsrFlow      = FALSE;      // DSR output flow control 
    dcb.fDtrControl       = 0;          //DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE; // DTR flow control type
    dcb.fRtsControl       = 0;          //RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE; // RTS flow control 
    dcb.fDsrSensitivity   = FALSE;      // DSR sensitivity 
    dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = FALSE;      // XOFF continues Tx 
    dcb.fOutX             = FALSE;      // XON/XOFF out flow control 
    dcb.fInX              = FALSE;      // XON/XOFF in flow control 
    dcb.fErrorChar        = FALSE;      // enable error replacement V2.12 TRUE -> FALSE
    dcb.fAbortOnError     = TRUE;       // abort reads/writes on error 
    dcb.XonChar           = 0x00;       // Tx and Rx XON character 0x01
    dcb.XoffChar          = 0x00;       // Tx and Rx XOFF character 0x02
    dcb.ErrorChar         = 0x1f;       // error replacement character  
    dcb.EofChar           = 0x0d;       // end of input character 0x00
    dcb.EvtChar           = 0x00;       // received event character 0x0d

    if (SetCommState(handle, &dcb))
    {
        EscapeCommFunction(handle, SETRTS);
        EscapeCommFunction(handle, SETDTR);
        EscapeCommFunction(handle, CLRRTS);
        EscapeCommFunction(handle, CLRDTR);
        PurgeComm(handle, PURGE_TXCLEAR | PURGE_RXCLEAR);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. You have to read the byes as they arrive and cope with CR yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's very unlikely to work.  Windows itself doesn't do anything with the DCB.EofChar you specify.  Or for that matter any of the other special characters in the DCB.  It directly passes it to the device driver, the underlying ioctl is [IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Leaving it entirely up to the driver to implement them.

Most hardware vendors that write serial port drivers (USB emulators most of all these days), use the sample driver code that's included in the WDK.  Which does *nothing* with SERIAL_CHARS.EofChar.  So the inevitable outcome is that nobody implements it.  I personally have never encountered one, knowingly anyway.

So it is expected not to have any effect.

You can usually expect DCB.EvtChar to work, it powers the EV_RXFLAG option for WaitCommEvent().  In other words, if you set it to the line terminator then it can give you a signal that ReadFile() is going to return *at least* a complete line.

But you explicitly said you don't want to do this.  Everybody solves this by simply buffering the extra data that is returned by ReadFile().  Or by reading one byte at a time, which is okay because serial ports are slow anyway.

Comment: My current "solution" works with one byte at a time. I wished to avoid that because of _theretically unnecessary_ CPU usage. ... oh well.

Comment: Then you have to read the port using larger buffers and cache any read data off to the side, scanning that cache for new CRs each time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In my case the incoming data are responses (like a server side response). Unknown length but they end with `0x0d`. The _com server_ is silent when I don't ask it anything. So my buffer wont be filled completely every time when the reply message ends.